# API Gateway Cloudformation CORS

Tags: cors, aws-lambda, aws-cloudformation, aws-api-gateway

I'm trying to deploy an API in API Gateway using cloudformation. The methods require CORS to be enabled, I followed the template here [Enable CORS for API Gateway in Cloudformation template](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40292888/enable-cors-for-api-gateway-in-cloudformation-template) to do so.  Here is my template

```
AuthorizerRole:
    Type: AWS::IAM::Role
    Properties:
      AssumeRolePolicyDocument:
        Version: "2012-10-17"
        Statement:
          - Action:
              - "sts:AssumeRole"
            Effect: "Allow"
            Principal:
              Service:
                - "apigateway.amazonaws.com"
      Policies:
        - PolicyDocument:
            Version: "2012-10-17"
            Statement:
              - Action:
                  - "lambda:invokeFunction"
                Effect: "Allow"
                Resource:
                  - !GetAtt "MyAPIAuthorizer.Arn"
          PolicyName: "lambda"

Authorizer:
  Type: AWS::ApiGateway::Authorizer
  Properties:
    AuthorizerResultTtlInSeconds: 0
    AuthorizerCredentials: !GetAtt "AuthorizerRole.Arn"
    AuthorizerUri:
      Fn::Join:
        - ""
        -
          - "arn:aws:apigateway:"
          - Ref: "AWS::Region"
          - ":lambda:path/2015-03-31/functions/"
          - Fn::GetAtt:
              - "MyAPIAuthorizer"
              - "Arn"
          - "/invocations"
    Type: "TOKEN"
    IdentitySource: "method.request.header.token"
    Name: "DefaultAuthorizer"
    RestApiId: !Ref RestApi

MyAPIAuthorizer:
    Type: AWS::Lambda::Function
    Properties:
      Code:
        S3Bucket: my-My-lambda-us-east-1
        S3Key: node_lambdas.zip
      Handler: My-APIAuthorizer.handler
      Role: !Ref Role
      Runtime: nodejs6.10
      Timeout: 300
      VpcConfig:
        SecurityGroupIds:
          - !Ref SecurityGroup
        SubnetIds: !Ref Subnets

MyAuthenticateUser:
    Type: AWS::Lambda::Function
    Properties:
      Code:
        S3Bucket: My-My-lambda-us-east-1
        S3Key: node_lambdas.zip
      Handler: My-AuthenticateUser.handler
      Role: !Ref Role
      Runtime: nodejs6.10
      Timeout: 300
      VpcConfig:
        SecurityGroupIds:
          - !Ref SecurityGroup
        SubnetIds: !Ref Subnets
      #Policies: AWSLambdaDynamoDBExecutionRole

MyAuthenticateUserApiGatewayInvoke:
    Type: AWS::Lambda::Permission
    Properties:
      Action: lambda:InvokeFunction
      FunctionName: !GetAtt "MyAuthenticateUser.Arn"
      Principal: "apigateway.amazonaws.com"
      SourceArn: !Sub "arn:aws:execute-api:${AWS::Region}:${AWS::AccountId}:${RestApi}/*/*/*"
MyAuthenticateUserResource:
     Type: AWS::ApiGateway::Resource
     Properties:
       RestApiId: !Ref RestApi
       ParentId: !Ref ApiResourceParent
       PathPart: authenticateuser
MyAuthenticateUserPost:
      Type: AWS::ApiGateway::Method
      Properties:
        RestApiId: !Ref RestApi
        ResourceId: !Ref MyAuthenticateUserResource
        HttpMethod: POST
        AuthorizationType: NONE
        Integration:
          IntegrationHttpMethod: POST
          Type: AWS
          Uri: !Sub
            - "arn:aws:apigateway:${AWS::Region}:lambda:path/2015-03-31/functions/${lambdaArn}/invocations"
            - lambdaArn: !GetAtt "MyAuthenticateUser.Arn"
          IntegrationResponses:
          - StatusCode: 200
            ResponseParameters:
              method.response.header.Access-Control-Allow-Origin: "'*'"
        MethodResponses:
        - StatusCode: 200
          ResponseModels:
            application/json: 'Empty'
          ResponseParameters:
              method.response.header.Access-Control-Allow-Origin: true
MyAuthenticateUserOptions:
      Type: AWS::ApiGateway::Method
      Properties:
        RestApiId: !Ref RestApi
        ResourceId: !Ref MyAuthenticateUserResource
        HttpMethod: OPTIONS
        AuthorizationType: NONE
        Integration:
            IntegrationHttpMethod: POST
            IntegrationResponses:
            - StatusCode: 200
              ResponseParameters:
                method.response.header.Access-Control-Allow-Headers: "'Content-Type,X-Amz-Date,Authorization,X-Api-Key,X-Amz-Security-Token,token'"
                method.response.header.Access-Control-Allow-Methods: "'POST,OPTIONS'"
                method.response.header.Access-Control-Allow-Origin: "'*'"
            Type: MOCK
        MethodResponses:
        - StatusCode: 200
          ResponseModels:
            application/json: 'Empty'
          ResponseParameters:
              method.response.header.Access-Control-Allow-Headers: true
              method.response.header.Access-Control-Allow-Methods: true
              method.response.header.Access-Control-Allow-Origin: true

MyFunction:
    Type: AWS::Lambda::Function
    Properties:
      Code:
        S3Bucket: My-My-lambda-us-east-1
        S3Key: node_lambdas.zip
      Handler: My-Function.handler
      Role: !Ref Role
      Runtime: nodejs6.10
      Timeout: 300
      VpcConfig:
        SecurityGroupIds:
          - !Ref SecurityGroup
        SubnetIds: !Ref Subnets
      #Policies: AWSLambdaDynamoDBExecutionRole

MyFunctionApiGatewayInvoke:
    Type: AWS::Lambda::Permission
    Properties:
      Action: lambda:InvokeFunction
      FunctionName: !GetAtt "MyFunction.Arn"
      Principal: "apigateway.amazonaws.com"
      SourceArn: !Sub "arn:aws:execute-api:${AWS::Region}:${AWS::AccountId}:${RestApi}/*/*/*"
MyFunctionResource:
     Type: AWS::ApiGateway::Resource
     Properties:
       RestApiId: !Ref RestApi
       ParentId: !Ref ApiResourceParent
       PathPart: Function
MyFunctionGet:
      Type: AWS::ApiGateway::Method
      Properties:
        RestApiId: !Ref RestApi
        ResourceId: !Ref MyFunctionResource
        HttpMethod: GET
        AuthorizationType: CUSTOM
        AuthorizerId: !Ref Authorizer
        Integration:
          IntegrationHttpMethod: GET
          Type: AWS
          Uri: !Sub
            - "arn:aws:apigateway:${AWS::Region}:lambda:path/2015-03-31/functions/${lambdaArn}/invocations"
            - lambdaArn: !GetAtt "MyFunction.Arn"
          IntegrationResponses:
          - StatusCode: 200
            ResponseParameters:
              method.response.header.Access-Control-Allow-Origin: "'*'"
        MethodResponses:
        - StatusCode: 200
          ResponseModels:
            application/json: 'Empty'
          ResponseParameters:
              method.response.header.Access-Control-Allow-Origin: true
MyFunctionOptions:
      Type: AWS::ApiGateway::Method
      Properties:
        RestApiId: !Ref RestApi
        ResourceId: !Ref MyFunctionResource
        HttpMethod: OPTIONS
        AuthorizationType: NONE
        Integration:
            IntegrationHttpMethod: GET
            IntegrationResponses:
            - StatusCode: 200
              ResponseParameters:
                method.response.header.Access-Control-Allow-Headers: "'Content-Type,X-Amz-Date,Authorization,X-Api-Key,X-Amz-Security-Token,token'"
                method.response.header.Access-Control-Allow-Methods: "'GET,OPTIONS'"
                method.response.header.Access-Control-Allow-Origin: "'*'"
            Type: MOCK
        MethodResponses:
        - StatusCode: 200
          ResponseModels:
            application/json: 'Empty'
          ResponseParameters:
              method.response.header.Access-Control-Allow-Headers: true
              method.response.header.Access-Control-Allow-Methods: true
              method.response.header.Access-Control-Allow-Origin: true
```

After deploying the API the `MyAuthenticateUserPost` method returns a 200 with the following response headers

> Access-Control-Allow-Origin →*
>
> Connection →keep-alive
>
> Content-Length→249
>
> Content-Type →application/json
>
> Date →Fri, 28 Sep 2018 21:15:38 GMT
>
> Via →1.1 sdlkfnsdlk.cloudfront.net(CloudFront)
>
> X-Amz-Cf-Id→dflknsdlfkn
>
> X-Amzn-Trace-Id →Root=sdlkfnsdlk;Sampled=0
>
> X-Cache →Miss from cloudfront
>
> x-amz-apigw-id →sdklfnsdlk
>
> x-amzn-RequestId →slkfnlsdk

but the `MyFunctionGet` method returns a 500 with the following response headers

> Connection →keep-alive
>
> Content-Length →36
>
> Content-Type →application/json
>
> Date →Fri, 28 Sep 2018 21:19:04 GMT
>
> Via →1.1 slkdfnk.cloudfront.net (CloudFront)
>
> X-Amz-Cf-Id →dsklfnsdlk
>
> X-Cache →Error from cloudfront
>
> x-amz-apigw-id →dlsfknsdlkfn
>
> x-amzn-RequestId →sdkfnsdkln

The 500 response is missing the `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` and `X-Amzn-Trace-Id` headers.  The difference between the 2 methods is that the working method is a POST and has no authorization while the one that doesn't work is a GET and has a custom Authorizer.  I can make the method returning a 500 work if I go into the API Gateway console, select the GET method->Integration Request, and save the Lambda Function like so
[image]

That function is already present in that field after the cloudformation deploy, and I've added the permission in the template, but the API Gateway method will not work unless I perform this manual step. I have about 50 methods so I would like to completely automate this.  Am I missing something in my template?

**Update:**
In response to @jny I updated the integration responses in my Get method like so

```
IntegrationResponses:
              - StatusCode: 200
                SelectionPattern: "2\\{d}2"
                ResponseParameters:
                  method.response.header.Access-Control-Allow-Origin: "'*'"
              - StatusCode: 300
                SelectionPattern: "3\\{d}2"
                ResponseParameters:
                  method.response.header.Access-Control-Allow-Origin: "'*'"
              - StatusCode: 400
                SelectionPattern: "4\\{d}2"
                ResponseParameters:
                  method.response.header.Access-Control-Allow-Origin: "'*'"
              - StatusCode: 500
                SelectionPattern: "5\\{d}2"
                ResponseParameters:
                  method.response.header.Access-Control-Allow-Origin: "'*'"
            MethodResponses:
            - StatusCode: 200
              ResponseModels:
                application/json: 'Empty'
              ResponseParameters:
                  method.response.header.Access-Control-Allow-Origin: true
            - StatusCode: 300
              ResponseModels:
                application/json: 'Empty'
              ResponseParameters:
                  method.response.header.Access-Control-Allow-Origin: true
            - StatusCode: 400
              ResponseModels:
                application/json: 'Empty'
              ResponseParameters:
                  method.response.header.Access-Control-Allow-Origin: true
            - StatusCode: 500
              ResponseModels:
                application/json: 'Empty'
              ResponseParameters:
                  method.response.header.Access-Control-Allow-Origin: true
```

I also made the same update to my options method

```
IntegrationResponses:
                - StatusCode: 200
                  SelectionPattern: "2\\{d}2"
                  ResponseParameters:
                    method.response.header.Access-Control-Allow-Headers: "'Content-Type,X-Amz-Date,Authorization,X-Api-Key,X-Amz-Security-Token,token'"
                    method.response.header.Access-Control-Allow-Methods: "'GET,OPTIONS'"
                    method.response.header.Access-Control-Allow-Origin: "'*'"
                - StatusCode: 300
                  SelectionPattern: "3\\{d}2"
                  ResponseParameters:
                    method.response.header.Access-Control-Allow-Headers: "'Content-Type,X-Amz-Date,Authorization,X-Api-Key,X-Amz-Security-Token,token'"
                    method.response.header.Access-Control-Allow-Methods: "'GET,OPTIONS'"
                    method.response.header.Access-Control-Allow-Origin: "'*'"
                - StatusCode: 400
                  SelectionPattern: "4\\{d}2"
                  ResponseParameters:
                    method.response.header.Access-Control-Allow-Headers: "'Content-Type,X-Amz-Date,Authorization,X-Api-Key,X-Amz-Security-Token,token'"
                    method.response.header.Access-Control-Allow-Methods: "'GET,OPTIONS'"
                    method.response.header.Access-Control-Allow-Origin: "'*'"
                - StatusCode: 500
                  SelectionPattern: "5\\{d}2"
                  ResponseParameters:
                    method.response.header.Access-Control-Allow-Headers: "'Content-Type,X-Amz-Date,Authorization,X-Api-Key,X-Amz-Security-Token,token'"
                    method.response.header.Access-Control-Allow-Methods: "'GET,OPTIONS'"
                    method.response.header.Access-Control-Allow-Origin: "'*'"
            MethodResponses:
            - StatusCode: 200
              ResponseModels:
                application/json: 'Empty'
              ResponseParameters:
                  method.response.header.Access-Control-Allow-Headers: false
                  method.response.header.Access-Control-Allow-Methods: false
                  method.response.header.Access-Control-Allow-Origin: false
            - StatusCode: 300
              ResponseModels:
                application/json: 'Empty'
              ResponseParameters:
                  method.response.header.Access-Control-Allow-Headers: false
                  method.response.header.Access-Control-Allow-Methods: false
                  method.response.header.Access-Control-Allow-Origin: false
            - StatusCode: 400
              ResponseModels:
                application/json: 'Empty'
              ResponseParameters:
                  method.response.header.Access-Control-Allow-Headers: false
                  method.response.header.Access-Control-Allow-Methods: false
                  method.response.header.Access-Control-Allow-Origin: false
            - StatusCode: 500
              ResponseModels:
                application/json: 'Empty'
              ResponseParameters:
                  method.response.header.Access-Control-Allow-Headers: false
                  method.response.header.Access-Control-Allow-Methods: false
                  method.response.header.Access-Control-Allow-Origin: false
```

I still see the 500 response when invoking the API method

Answer (score 0):

You have to configure ResponseParameters for all statuses, not just 200.

Something like that:

```
   "IntegrationResponses": [
        {
          "ResponseParameters":{
            "method.response.header.Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "'*'"
          },
        "StatusCode": 200,
        "ResponseTemplates": {
        ....
        }
      },
        {
          "StatusCode": 500,
          "SelectionPattern": "5\\{d}2",
          "ResponseTemplates": {
              ....
          }
        }
      ],
```

and same for method responses, e.g.:

```
"MethodResponses": [{
      "ResponseModels": {
        "application/json": "Empty"
      },
      "ResponseParameters":{
        "method.response.header.Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "'*'"
      },
      "StatusCode": "200"
    },
      {
        "StatusCode": "500"
      }
    ]
```

Comment: I added this but I still see the 500 response code.  I updated the question to show how I added response parameters