# CloudFormation API Gateway CORS issue access to XMLHttpRequest blocked

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation, aws-api-gateway

I'm trying to use CloudFormation to create an API Gateway but I have CORS issue with it.

Error on the front-end:

```sh
POST https://<>.execute-api.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/prod/<> 500
new:1 Access to XMLHttpRequest at '<>' from origin 'http://localhost:3000' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.
```

- The API is created without any issue and I even double check **every single page** on the console against the working API and find no differences in their `Method Request`, `Integration Request`, `Integration Response` and `Method Response` for all the methods (including the `OPTIONS`).
- If I remove the resources created by the template and create them manually in the same API gateway then my code works as expected. I've tested with the localhost, front-end code in S3 bucket and PostMan, so I can verify that my front-end code, lambda functions and database are working correctly.
- I understand that people have had this issue before but I haven't been able to find any answer that solves my issue.
- Here's [my template](https://gist.github.com/nguyendviet/3078cc975d4111a2c6d380d0dd587168).
- Please note that the `"method.response.header.Access-Control-Allow-Origin": false` actually creates the API with the same settings as the working one.
- I also use the code from the [correct answer for this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40292888/enable-cors-for-api-gateway-in-cloudformation-template).
- Yes, my OPTIONS request has the "Access-Control-Allow-Origin" header.

### Update

Following dannymac's answer below. I got these:

- I added `console.log(event.requestContext);` to my Lambda function (written in Node.js).
- There are logs for Lambda when I test the function.

```sh
2019-06-27T20:07:03.118Z    462b93b2-9d4b-4ed3-bc04-f966fcd034cf    Debug CORS issue. Request ID:
2019-06-27T20:07:03.118Z    462b93b2-9d4b-4ed3-bc04-f966fcd034cf    undefined
```

- It looks like there is no `event.requestContext`.
- I selected `Enable CloudWatch Logs-INFO` and `Enable Detailed CloudWatch Metrics` with `CloudWatch log role ARN*:arn:aws:iam::<ID>:role/ApiGatewayCloudWatchLogsRole` (it's a role created by AWS) in the `API Gateway` settings.
- However, there is no `CloudWatch` log for the `API Gateway`. There's a default log in `CloudWatch - Log Groups`: `/aws/apigateway/welcome`

```sh
Time (UTC +00:00)
2019-06-27
19:50:55
Cloudwatch logs enabled for API Gateway
```

- It looks like the `CloudWatch` log didn't pick up the test from `API Gateway`.
- This is what I got from testing the `GET` method in my `API Gateway`:

```sh
Response Body
{
  "message": "Internal server error"
}
Response Headers
{}
Logs
Execution log for request 10d90173-9919-11e9-82e1-dd33dda3b9df
Thu Jun 27 20:20:54 UTC 2019 : Starting execution for request: 10d90173-9919-11e9-82e1-dd33dda3b9df
Thu Jun 27 20:20:54 UTC 2019 : HTTP Method: GET, Resource Path: /notes
Thu Jun 27 20:20:54 UTC 2019 : Method request path: {}
Thu Jun 27 20:20:54 UTC 2019 : Method request query string: {userid=<ID>}
Thu Jun 27 20:20:54 UTC 2019 : Method request headers: {}
Thu Jun 27 20:20:54 UTC 2019 : Method request body before transformations: 
Thu Jun 27 20:20:54 UTC 2019 : Endpoint request URI: https://lambda.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/2015-03-31/functions/arn:aws:lambda:us-east-1:770402430649:function:test-api-gateway-2-LambdaFunction-1XDONAN3QIY9I/invocations
Thu Jun 27 20:20:54 UTC 2019 : Endpoint request headers: {x-amzn-lambda-integration-tag=... [TRUNCATED]
Thu Jun 27 20:20:54 UTC 2019 : Endpoint request body after transformations: {"resource":"/notes","path":"/notes","httpMethod":"GET","headers":null,"multiValueHeaders":null,"queryStringParameters":{"userid":"<USERID>"},"multiValueQueryStringParameters":{"userid":["<USERID>"]},"pathParameters":null,"stageVariables":null,"requestContext":{"path":"/notes","accountId":"<ID>"...,"identity":{"cognitoIdentityPoolId":null,"cognitoIdentityId":null,"apiKey":"test-invoke-api-key","principalOrgId":null,"cognitoAuthenticationType":null,"userArn":"<ARN>","apiKeyId":"test-invoke-api-key-id","userAgent":..."test [TRUNCATED]
Thu Jun 27 20:20:54 UTC 2019 : Sending request to https://lambda.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/2015-03-31/functions/arn:aws:lambda:us-east-1:<ID>:function:test-api-gateway-2-LambdaFunction-<STRING>/invocations
Thu Jun 27 20:20:54 UTC 2019 : Received response. Status: 403, Integration latency: 6 ms
Thu Jun 27 20:20:54 UTC 2019 : Endpoint response headers: {Date=Thu, 27 Jun 2019 20:20:54 GMT, Content-Length=130, Connection=keep-alive, x-amzn-RequestId=<ID>}
Thu Jun 27 20:20:54 UTC 2019 : Endpoint response body before transformations: <AccessDeniedException>
  <Message>Unable to determine service/operation name to be authorized</Message>
</AccessDeniedException>

Thu Jun 27 20:20:54 UTC 2019 : Lambda invocation failed with status: 403. Lambda request id: feb22917-0dea-4f91-a274-fb6b85a69121
Thu Jun 27 20:20:54 UTC 2019 : Execution failed due to configuration error: 
Thu Jun 27 20:20:54 UTC 2019 : Method completed with status: 500
```

- I've also exported both the working and not working API Gateway in Swagger 2. The only difference is:

```
// working one:
"x-amazon-apigateway-any-method": {
        "produces": [
          "application/json"
        ],
        "parameters": [
          {
            "name": "noteid",
            "in": "path",
            "required": true,
            "type": "string"
          }
        ],
        "responses": {
          "200": {
            "description": "200 response",
            "schema": {
              "$ref": "#/definitions/Empty"
            }
          }
        },
        "security": [
          {
            "mobile-notes-api-authorizer": []
          }
        ]
      }
```

```
// not working one:
"x-amazon-apigateway-any-method": {
        "produces": [
          "application/json"
        ],
        "responses": {
          "200": {
            "description": "200 response",
            "schema": {
              "$ref": "#/definitions/Empty"
            }
          }
        },
        "security": [
          {
            "test-api-gateway-2-authorizer": []
          }
        ]
      }
```

- They both have:

```
"headers": {
              "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": {
                "type": "string"
              },
              "Access-Control-Allow-Methods": {
                "type": "string"
              },
              "Access-Control-Allow-Headers": {
                "type": "string"
              }
            }
```

- I've tried to use the Swagger template in the `Body` of my API Gateway before but unable to solve the invalid authorizer issue.

Comment: Sometimes this happens when the preflight OPTIONS request doesn't have the "Access-Control-Allow-Origin" header, have you checked it already?

Comment: Maybe this will be helpful for you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40292888/enable-cors-for-api-gateway-in-cloudformation-template

Comment: Thanks @DeependraDangal, if you look at my template, I use the code from that corrected answer.

Comment: Thank you @halfer, I'll keep that in mind.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've figured out the issue. There are 2 main things:

1. The `IntegrationHttpMethod` for Lambda must be POST. I found the answer [here](https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?threadID=209420).
2. The template didn't have `AWS::Lambda::Permission` that allows API Gateway to invoke Lambda function.
   With the template, when you use `AWS::Lambda::Permission`, it will show the API as a trigger of your Lambda function.
   However, if you manually create the API Gateway and link it with your Lambda function, it won't show API Gateway as a trigger but it still works.

So for the template I posted above, I needed to add these for it to work:

```
"LambdaPermission": {
            "Type": "AWS::Lambda::Permission",
            "Description": "Permission for API GateWay to invoke Lambda.",
            "Properties": {
                "Action": "lambda:invokeFunction",
                "FunctionName": {
                    "Fn::GetAtt": [
                        "LambdaFunction",
                        "Arn"
                    ]
                },
                "Principal": "apigateway.amazonaws.com",
                "SourceArn": {
                    "Fn::Join": [
                        "",
                        [
                            "arn:aws:execute-api:",
                            {
                                "Ref": "AWS::Region"
                            },
                            ":",
                            {
                                "Ref": "AWS::AccountId"
                            },
                            ":",
                            {
                                "Ref": "ApiGateway"
                            },
                            "/*"
                        ]
                    ]
                }
            }
        },
```

And edit method ANY to look like this

```
"methodNotesANY": {
            "Type": "AWS::ApiGateway::Method",
            "DependsOn": "LambdaPermission",
            "Properties": {
                "AuthorizationType": "COGNITO_USER_POOLS",
                "AuthorizerId": {
                    "Ref": "GatewayAuthorizer"
                },
                "RestApiId": {
                    "Ref": "ApiGateway"
                },
                "ResourceId": {
                    "Ref": "resourceNotes"
                },
                "HttpMethod": "ANY",
                "Integration": {
                    "Type": "AWS_PROXY",
                    "IntegrationHttpMethod": "POST",
                    "Uri": {
                        "Fn::Sub": "arn:aws:apigateway:${AWS::Region}:lambda:path/2015-03-31/functions/${LambdaFunction.Arn}/invocations"
                    },
                    "IntegrationResponses": [{
                        "StatusCode": "200"
                    }]
                },
                "MethodResponses": [{
                    "ResponseModels": {
                        "application/json": "Empty"
                    },
                    "StatusCode": "200"
                }]
            }
        },
```

Comment: I wish I saw your answer earlier... would've saved me hours of digging...

Answer (score 1):

**My Best Guess**: The `POST` to your `ANY` lambda function is failing during execution, and not setting the `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` header to `*` (or your domain).  Anytime I get a `5XX` error and a `CORS` error at the same time from a non-`OPTIONS` request, this is almost always the case for me.

**Recommended Next Steps**: Reproduce the error situation after adding debug logging to your Lambda source code, and turning on CloudWatch Logs in your API Gateway Rest API.  You can do this by going to the API Gateway console, clicking on `Stages` > `Prod` > `Logs/Tracing`, then checking these two: `Enable CloudWatch Logs` (Log level: `INFO`), and `Enable Detailed CloudWatch Metrics`.  Then you must "deploy" the changes in order for them to take effect.  Do this by clicking the `Actions` button from your Rest API's `Resources` menu, and choosing `Deploy API`.  I also recommend logging the `extendedRequestId` (an event property passed to your handler) from your Lambda function in order to tie the Lambda request to the API Gateway request: `event.requestContext.extendedRequestId`.

Example API Gateway logs:

```
(b66b3876-984b-11e9-95eb-dd93c7e40ca0) Extended Request Id: b5zpBGS3IAMFvqw=
(b66b3876-984b-11e9-95eb-dd93c7e40ca0) Verifying Usage Plan for request: b66b3876-984b-11e9-95eb-dd93c7e40ca0. API Key: API Stage: 1234567890/Prod
(b66b3876-984b-11e9-95eb-dd93c7e40ca0) API Key authorized because method 'ANY /forms' does not require API Key. Request will not contribute to throttle or quota limits
(b66b3876-984b-11e9-95eb-dd93c7e40ca0) Usage Plan check succeeded for API Key and API Stage 1234567890/Prod
(b66b3876-984b-11e9-95eb-dd93c7e40ca0) Starting execution for request: b66b3876-984b-11e9-95eb-dd93c7e40ca0
(b66b3876-984b-11e9-95eb-dd93c7e40ca0) HTTP Method: GET, Resource Path: /forms
(b66b3876-984b-11e9-95eb-dd93c7e40ca0) Lambda execution failed with status 200 due to customer function error: select count(*) AS `count(*)` from (select `user`.* from `user` where (id IN ('some_id_123'))) as `temp` - Cannot enqueue Query after fatal error.. Lambda request id: 1ae2bb06-5347-4775-9277-caccc42f18f2
(b66b3876-984b-11e9-95eb-dd93c7e40ca0) Method completed with status: 502
(b66b3876-984b-11e9-95eb-dd93c7e40ca0) AWS Integration Endpoint RequestId : 1ae2bb06-5347-4775-9277-caccc42f18f2
(b66b3876-984b-11e9-95eb-dd93c7e40ca0) X-ray Tracing ID : 1-5d13cca0-3be96a1ab93a877edc70577c
```

Example correlated Lambda execution logs:

```
START RequestId: 1ae2bb06-5347-4775-9277-caccc42f18f2 Version: $LATEST
2019-06-26T19:50:56.391Z  1ae2bb06-5347-4775-9277-caccc42f18f2 { "extendedRequestId": "b5zpBGS3IAMFvqw=", ... }
2019-06-26T19:50:57.853Z  1ae2bb06-5347-4775-9277-caccc42f18f2 { "errorMessage": "select count(*) AS `count(*)` from (select `user`.* from `user` where (id IN ('some_id_123'))) as `temp` - Cannot enqueue Query after fatal error.", ... }
END RequestId: 1ae2bb06-5347-4775-9277-caccc42f18f2
REPORT RequestId: 1ae2bb06-5347-4775-9277-caccc42f18f2  Duration: 1660.45 ms  Billed Duration: 1700 ms Memory Size: 256 MB  Max Memory Used: 57 MB
```

**Other Thoughts**: Export the Swagger definitions of both the broken API and the working API.  Compare and see what is different.  Do this from the console by going to `Stages` > `Prod` > `Export` > `Export as Swagger + API Gateway Extensions`.  It may not be exactly the same as the CloudFormation template, but it's pretty close.

Comment: Thank you so so much @dannymac! Let me try what you suggested and get back to you.

Comment: About the `swagger` export. I've done that and also `openAPI` but I was unable to make the `swagger` or `openAPI` code work inside the `Body` property of the `AWS::ApiGateway::RestApi` due to the Authorizer's issue. I'll update my question.

Comment: I've done what you suggested but unable to find the issue. I've updated my question above.

Answer (score 0):

At the time of this post, Lambda Proxy Integration (AWS_PROXY) and CORS (Access-Control-Allow-Origin) don't work very well together. My approach -inspired on [this explanation](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73210861/2197207)- was to use AWS instead of AWS_PROXY and manually provide Mapping templates for both request and response as follows:

```yaml
MyApiGateway:
  Type: AWS::Serverless::Api
  Properties:
    StageName: !Ref Stage
    Cors:
      AllowMethods: "'POST,OPTIONS'"
      AllowHeaders: "'Access-Control-Allow-Origin,Content-Type,X-Amz-Date,Authorization,X-Api-Key,x-requested-with,x-requested-for'"
      AllowOrigin: "'*'"
    DefinitionBody:
      swagger: 2.0
      info:
        version: 1.1
        title: !Ref AWS::StackName
      paths:
        /mypath:
          get:
            responses:
              "200":
                schema:
                  $ref: "#/definitions/Empty"
                headers:
                  Access-Control-Allow-Origin:
                    type: string
            x-amazon-apigateway-integration:
              httpMethod: POST # must be POST even for GET
              type: AWS # must be AWS to allow cors headers
              uri: !Sub arn:aws:apigateway:${AWS::Region}:lambda:path/2015-03-31/functions/${MyLambda.Arn}/invocations
              requestTemplates:
                application/json: |
                  {
                    #set($params = $input.params().querystring)
                    "queryStringParameters" : {
                      #foreach($param in $params.keySet())
                        "$param" : "$util.escapeJavaScript($params.get($param))" #if($foreach.hasNext),#end
                      #end
                    },
                    #set($params = $input.params().path)
                    "pathParameters" : {
                      #foreach($param in $params.keySet())
                        "$param" : "$util.escapeJavaScript($params.get($param))" #if($foreach.hasNext),#end
                      #end
                    }
                  }
              responses:
                default:
                  statusCode: 200
                  responseParameters:
                    method.response.header.Access-Control-Allow-Origin: "'*'"
                  responseTemplates:
                    application/json: |
                      #set($payload = $util.parseJson($input.json('$')))
                      #set($context.responseOverride.status = $payload.statusCode)
                      $payload.body
```