# Not able to enable the cors of APIgateway via CFT. But we are able to do it manually using the console

Tags: cors, aws-cloudformation, aws-api-gateway

Not able to enable the cors of  APIgateway via CFT. But we are able to do it manually using the console.

I also use the code in the correct answer in the below to questions:

1. [Enable CORS for API Gateway in Cloudformation template](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40292888/enable-cors-for-api-gateway-in-cloudformation-template) .
2. [CloudFormation API Gateway CORS issue access to XMLHttpRequest blocked](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56688796/cloudformation-api-gateway-cors-issue-access-to-xmlhttprequest-blocked/56811229#56811229)

Need a sample CFT template that enables CORS directly.