# AWS - Cloudfront distribution + API Gateway - 403 Forbidden

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation, aws-api-gateway, amazon-cloudfront

I'm trying to serve a API Gateway from a Cloudfront distribution but I'm still getting a 403 response even though deployment has no error.

Calling endpoint via its invoke url from web console works right, expected data is returned.

The distribution also serve a static site from an S3 bucket, but that works perfectly.

The distribution is configured to log to an S3 bucket, but logs are not of help (see below).

Probably I'm missing some configuration, but I really can't tell what nor where.

##### Cloudformation template

```yaml
Distribution:
    Type: AWS::CloudFront::Distribution
    Properties:
      DistributionConfig:
        Enabled: true
        HttpVersion: http2
        Origins:
          - Id: Bucket
            # ...
          - Id: ApiGateway
            DomainName: !Sub '${ApiGateway.RestApiId}.execute-api.${AWS::Region}.amazonaws.com'
            CustomOriginConfig:
              OriginProtocolPolicy: https-only
              HTTPPort: 80
              HTTPSPort: 443
        DefaultRootObject: index.html
        DefaultCacheBehavior:
          Compress: true
          ViewerProtocolPolicy: allow-all
          TargetOriginId: Bucket
          CachePolicyId: 658327ea-f89d-4fab-a63d-7e88639e58f6   # default CachingOptimized
        CacheBehaviors:
          - PathPattern: /api/*
            TargetOriginId: ApiGateway
            AllowedMethods: [ GET, HEAD, OPTIONS]
            ViewerProtocolPolicy: redirect-to-https
            CachePolicyId: 4135ea2d-6df8-44a3-9df3-4b5a84be39ad # CachingDisabled
          - TargetOriginId: Bucket
            # ...
        Logging:
            # ...

  ApiGateway:
    Type: AWS::ApiGateway::RestApi
    Properties:
      Name: !Sub my-api-gateway-${StageName}

  ApiGatewayExecutionRole:
    Type: AWS::IAM::Role
    Properties:
      RoleName: !Sub ApiGatewayExecutionRole-${StageName}
      ManagedPolicyArns:
        - arn:aws:iam::aws:policy/service-role/AmazonAPIGatewayPushToCloudWatchLogs
      AssumeRolePolicyDocument:
        Version: "2012-10-17"
        Statement:
          - Effect: Allow
            Principal:
              Service:
                - apigateway.amazonaws.com
            Action:
              - sts:AssumeRole

  ApiGatewayExecutionPolicy:
    Type: AWS::IAM::Policy
    DependsOn:
      - GetLatestArtistsExecutionRole
    Properties:
      PolicyName: !Sub ApiGatewayExecutionPolicy-${StageName}
      PolicyDocument:
        Version: "2012-10-17"
        Statement:
          - Effect: Allow
            Action:
              - lambda:InvokeFunction
            Resource: # a lambda ARN
          - Effect: Allow
            Action:
              - lambda:InvokeFunction
            Resource: # a lambda ARN
      Roles:
        - !Ref ApiGatewayExecutionRole
```

##### Logs

| date | time | x-edge-location | sc-bytes | cs-ip | cs-method | cs(Host) | cs-uri-stem | cs-status | cs(Referer) | cs(User-Agent) | cs-uri-query | cs(Cookie) | x-edge-result-type | x-edge-request-id | x-host-header | cs-protocol | cs-bytes | time-taken | x-forwarded-for | ssl-protocol | ssl-cipher | x-edge-response-result-type | cs-protocol-version | fle-status | fle-encrypted-fields | c-port | time-to-first-byte | x-edge-detailed-result-type | sc-content-type | sc-content-len | sc-range-start | sc-range-end |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2023-06-12 | 08:43:25 | PMO50-C1 | 484 | 93.56.216.51 | GET | 0123456789abcd.cloudfront.net | /favicon.ico | 403 | https://0123456789abcd.cloudfront.net/api/my/endpoint | Mozilla/5.0%20(X11;%20Linux%20x86_64)%20AppleWebKit/537.36%20(KHTML,%20like%20Gecko)%20Chrome/114.0.0.0%20Safari/537.36 | - | - | Error | VAvnzOY5Vg5Ra1jg5KeyQ7N986CUXU_ns76vHY_qdBNgMPeEE2p6yg== | 0123456789abcd.cloudfront.net | https | 423 | 0.204 | - | TLSv1.3 | TLS_AES_128_GCM_SHA256 | Error | HTTP/2.0 | - | - | 58248 | 0.204 | Error | application/xml | - | - | - |
| 2023-06-12 | 08:43:27 | PMO50-C1 | 417 | 93.56.216.51 | GET | 0123456789abcd.cloudfront.net | /api/my/endpoint | 403 | - | Mozilla/5.0%20(X11;%20Linux%20x86_64)%20AppleWebKit/537.36%20(KHTML,%20like%20Gecko)%20Chrome/114.0.0.0%20Safari/537.36 | - | - | Error | XwIBTQDx6c3Oaqq7xkNGrqa6WIpfELU0qbXnXGAKCrKvr9ZmMZmlsg== | 0123456789abcd.cloudfront.net | https | 206 | 0.150 | - | TLSv1.3 | TLS_AES_128_GCM_SHA256 | Error | HTTP/2.0 | - | - | 58248 | 0.150 | Error | application/json | 23 | - | - |
| 2023-06-12 | 08:43:27 | PMO50-C1 | 483 | 93.56.216.51 | GET | 0123456789abcd.cloudfront.net | /favicon.ico | 403 | https://0123456789abcd.cloudfront.net/api/my/endpoint | Mozilla/5.0%20(X11;%20Linux%20x86_64)%20AppleWebKit/537.36%20(KHTML,%20like%20Gecko)%20Chrome/114.0.0.0%20Safari/537.36 | - | - | Error | TGCaveojUlFJvx3cprpMpVTdtXPyPm9U2Xgxi4BFfSLhsdDGid9ykA== | 0123456789abcd.cloudfront.net | https | 34 | 0.163 | - | TLSv1.3 | TLS_AES_128_GCM_SHA256 | Error | HTTP/2.0 | - | - | 58248 | 0.163 | Error | application/xml | - | - | - |
| 2023-06-12 | 08:43:33 | PMO50-C1 | 416 | 93.56.216.51 | GET | 0123456789abcd.cloudfront.net | /api/my/endpoint | 403 | - | Mozilla/5.0%20(X11;%20Linux%20x86_64)%20AppleWebKit/537.36%20(KHTML,%20like%20Gecko)%20Chrome/114.0.0.0%20Safari/537.36 | - | - | Error | nnPavByn3z8KA8f9iM4ams5PW0K6ZJmjX_h_sK1D6wWvnRbRlw72ZA== | 0123456789abcd.cloudfront.net | https | 40 | 0.117 | - | TLSv1.3 | TLS_AES_128_GCM_SHA256 | Error | HTTP/2.0 | - | - | 58248 | 0.117 | Error | application/json | 23 | - | - |
| 2023-06-12 | 08:43:33 | PMO50-C1 | 484 | 93.56.216.51 | GET | 0123456789abcd.cloudfront.net | /favicon.ico | 403 | https://0123456789abcd.cloudfront.net/api/my/endpoint | Mozilla/5.0%20(X11;%20Linux%20x86_64)%20AppleWebKit/537.36%20(KHTML,%20like%20Gecko)%20Chrome/114.0.0.0%20Safari/537.36 | - | - | Error | 44ITHM9SfJGqEzHycOAkEuiMCFfVApgdV6UL9xXTZ0PLwjklhWokTA== | 0123456789abcd.cloudfront.net | https | 34 | 0.175 | - | TLSv1.3 | TLS_AES_128_GCM_SHA256 | Error | HTTP/2.0 | - | - | 58248 | 0.175 | Error | application/xml | - | - | - |
| 2023-06-12 | 08:45:34 | FCO50-P2 | 418 | 93.56.216.51 | GET | 0123456789abcd.cloudfront.net | /api/my/endpoint | 403 | - | Mozilla/5.0%20(X11;%20Linux%20x86_64)%20AppleWebKit/537.36%20(KHTML,%20like%20Gecko)%20Chrome/114.0.0.0%20Safari/537.36 | - | - | Error | 4crypFQbvDZ2uvu7VzSW_v7AM2b8MzweSHhQYDzk2njxICwW0Q8obw== | 0123456789abcd.cloudfront.net | https | 455 | 0.075 | - | TLSv1.3 | TLS_AES_128_GCM_SHA256 | Error | HTTP/2.0 | - | - | 44736 | 0.075 | Error | application/json | 23 | - | - |
| 2023-06-12 | 08:45:34 | FCO50-P2 | 483 | 93.56.216.51 | GET | 0123456789abcd.cloudfront.net | /favicon.ico | 403 | https://0123456789abcd.cloudfront.net/api/my/endpoint | Mozilla/5.0%20(X11;%20Linux%20x86_64)%20AppleWebKit/537.36%20(KHTML,%20like%20Gecko)%20Chrome/114.0.0.0%20Safari/537.36 | - | - | Error | TOnok3F9P8-Gi9CM_7GtHtOTmVhkyQPcrJrbwJlui4HUCXRZo-IA4A== | 0123456789abcd.cloudfront.net | https | 148 | 0.134 | - | TLSv1.3 | TLS_AES_128_GCM_SHA256 | Error | HTTP/2.0 | - | - | 44736 | 0.133 | Error | application/xml | - | - | - |
| 2023-06-12 | 08:45:42 | PMO50-C1 | 483 | 93.56.216.51 | GET | 0123456789abcd.cloudfront.net | /favicon.ico | 403 | https://0123456789abcd.cloudfront.net/api/my/endpoint | Mozilla/5.0%20(X11;%20Linux%20x86_64)%20AppleWebKit/537.36%20(KHTML,%20like%20Gecko)%20Chrome/114.0.0.0%20Safari/537.36 | - | - | Error | v--hpkzq7TxOTxgZgku6C8ZTllGu_8OuUdGDfoS-OCMnyp5aYpoT1g== | 0123456789abcd.cloudfront.net | https | 34 | 0.180 | - | TLSv1.3 | TLS_AES_128_GCM_SHA256 | Error | HTTP/2.0 | - | - | 58248 | 0.180 | Error | application/xml | - | - | - |

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are missing the CORS headers enabled in api gateway.

Try to enable them

```yaml
ApiGateway:
  Type: AWS::ApiGateway::RestApi
  Properties:
    Name: !Sub my-api-gateway-${StageName}
    EndpointConfiguration:
      Types:
        - REGIONAL
    Cors:
      AllowOrigins:
        - '*' # Replace '*' with the appropriate origin(s) if known
      AllowMethods:
        - GET
        - HEAD
        - OPTIONS
      AllowHeaders:
        - Content-Type
        - X-Amz-Date
        - Authorization
      MaxAge: 300
```

Comment: there is no `Cors` attribute in the [docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-resource-apigateway-restapi.html), are you sure about your code? any resource link?

Comment: It was missing informations my bad..
It should be in API Gateway V2 the core resource [API GateWay V2](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-properties-apigatewayv2-api-cors.html)

You can check this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40292888/enable-cors-for-api-gateway-in-cloudformation-template)

Comment: This [tutorial](https://medium.com/@joanisaac.biel/setting-up-cors-and-lambda-proxy-integration-in-aws-api-gateway-using-cloudformation-371312eebcb0) may help also

Answer (score 0):

Just ran into this problem myself and I found the answer thanks to [this post](https://medium.com/@steveb3210/apigatewayv2-cloudfront-distribution-and-cors-via-the-cdk-9bae7f22ecf8).

It turns out that if you pass all HTTP headers from CloudFront to API Gateway, it of course includes the `Host` header.  This causes API Gateway to see a request with a `Host` it does not know about, so it returns 403 Forbidden.

I had to block the Host header coming from CloudFront by specifying a custom origin request policy and that fixed the issue.  I'm using CDK so I did it like this:

```
const originRequestPolicy = new cdkCloudFront.OriginRequestPolicy(this, 'orp', {
  ...
  // Can't use `all()` because it will forward the Host header and API
  // Gateway will return 403 Forbidden because it doesn't recognise it.
  headerBehavior: cdkCloudFront.OriginRequestHeaderBehavior.denyList('host'),
  ...

new cdkCloudFront.Distribution(this, 'cfDist', {
  defaultBehavior: {
    originRequestPolicy: originRequestPolicy,
    ...
```

Hopefully you can translate this into CloudFormation if you are using that instead.  (Feel free to edit this answer and add the CloudFormation version if you have it.)